# Is it possible to have text cycle based on the date?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to the programming world and was wondering if it is possible to do something like the following:

Jan 1 - March 15 the div says "This is the first quarter"

March 16 - June 30 it says "This is the second quarter"

July 1 - October 1 it says "You have entered the third quarter"

October 2 - December 31 it says "This is the last quarter"

That was just an example. I want the text to cycle through different strings automatically without manually changing them every "quarter". I want to be able to set the dates that the text changes.

If it is possible (which I assume it is) would somebody be willing to write me a code that would do that (preferably one that can be written on the same page as the rest of the html/css - if it can't be done I'm sorry. Like I said I'm really new to all of this and I kinda already feel stupid...)? I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: give it a try before asking for a solution please. :)

Comment: I really don't know where to start. If I'm being perfectly honest, I don't really want to discover how to write the code, but rather just need the code for one small thing on my website. I know that makes me sound selfish, but is it not something simple? Besides, I learn by seeing code and going through it bit by bit rather than by frustratingly piecing it together on my own. (I didn't sound rude, did I? Sorry if I did :( )

Comment: Certainly it can be done. But this is a place for getting help with **your** script, not asking others to do it for you. E.g. you might create an array of objects with start date, end date and message properties and appropriate values. Then cycle through them based on the current date to see which to apply. There are other approaches.

Comment: Oh, I haven't used this site all that much either. I guess I'm not at the appropriate place then :( Sorry everyone!

P.S. I am EXTREMELY new, I barely understood what you were saying, but it kinda makes sense. I might be able to do this on my own, but I'm afraid it would take me SO much longer than asking on the appropriate forum. Thanks everyone for your replies.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about request for code rather than help with coding.

Answer (score 0):

This JSFiddle illustrates exactly what you outlined above: http://jsfiddle.net/eat_sleep_code/3deYQ/2/

You can alter the logic to suit your needs.

**HTML**

```
<span id="Quarter"></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var currentQuarter = getQuarter(today);
    $('#Quarter').html(currentQuarter);
});

function getQuarter(date)
{
    var result = '';
    if (date >= ParseQuarter('01/01/') && date <= ParseQuarter('03/15/'))
    {
        result = 'This is the first quarter';
    }
    else if (date >= ParseQuarter('03/16/') && date <= ParseQuarter('06/30/'))
    {
        result = 'This is the second quarter';
    }
    else if (date >= ParseQuarter('07/01/') && date <= ParseQuarter('10/01/'))
    {
        result = 'This is the third quarter';
    }
    else if (date >= ParseQuarter('10/02/') && date <= ParseQuarter('12/31/'))
    {
        result = 'This is the fourth quarter';
    }
    return result;    
}

function ParseQuarter(partialDate)
{
    var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    return Date.parse(partialDate + thisYear); 
}
```

As always, please vote for valid answers on StackOverflow!